# Difference between Import-Package resolution:=optional and no dependency at all

Tags: osgi

I have read [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4/esb_deploy_osgi/BestPractices-BuildBundles.html#BestPractices-BuildBundles-UOIWC) to use the optional resolution within the "Import-Package" directive carefully, but don't really understand why. Also what is the difference between optional and not specifying a dependency at all?

Comment: That link seems to be out of date. Is there an updated link available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you fail to specify an Import-Package at all, then your bundle cannot access the package *even if it available and exported by some other bundle*.

If you import the package optionally, then your bundle can use it if available, but that package not being available does not prevent resolution of your bundle.

You should avoid optional dependencies at the package level. Either you depend on a package or you don't. Normally a need for optional dependencies indicates that your bundle has poor coherency, i.e. it's doing too many unrelated things within one module.

Answer (score 0):

If you say it is optional, than it might occur if it is exported from some other bundle. If you do not import it at all, it will be never available for the bundle.
So, for what do you need it?
If you really have an optional part in your bundle, you can import the optional dependencies. However, you have to check if they are there when you use it.

OSGi will not complain if an optional import can not be found, but the JVM will complain if you bundles uses something which is not imported at all.

Comment: Will OSGi the one who complains if I use something not imported (if so, when? on installation?) or will the JVM throw a ClassNotFound exception? Also, how can one check whether a package is there/exported on runtime?

Comment: The JVM will complain, sorry. You can check it with the OSGi console, depending on your OSGi implementation used

Comment: I see: without import I will definitely have NO access to the package. But the question of querying on runtime (in my code) whether a package is enabled still remains...